# Why does the "continue" command appear on some google sheets but not others

Tags: google-sheets

I have two google sheets.  In one I have created a function and want to put it into the other.  In the first sheet it works great and has no issues, in the second sheet it seems to automatically insert the "continue(1,2,) etc.

The code I have, which works in the first sheet is:

```
=SPLIT(ADDTOTAL(SORT('REPORT LOOKUP'!F1:F35)),",")
```

(Addtotal is a custom script) but in the second sheet where it seems to autoinsert the "continue" it has duplicates and additional columns.

Anyone know what the issue woudl be, how I can turn off the continue if I need to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sigh- much pain could have been avoided if I had checked dates the sheets were created.  The difference is that the one sheet is a new google doc, the other old.  The new sheets do not behave the same way as the old, they no longer use the "continue" function but just post the data.